# InstallScript Reboot after multiple prequisites

Tags: installscript

My product uses an InstallScript 2014 project that has multiple prerequisites (PRQ). Sometimes one or more of these PRQs requires that the machine be rebooted. I have set the PRQ Editor Behavior tab to "Note it, fail to resume if the machine is rebooted, and reboot after the installation", and have set the return codes as 1641 and 3010, both of which indicate that a [restart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368542(VS.85).aspx) is required.

I interpret the Behavior setting to indicate that once ALL of the prerequisites have been installed and after MY application is installed that computer will be rebooted. However, this is not the case - the reboot never occurs.

Could it be that if PRQ #1 requests a reboot but PRQ does not, the "note" for a reboot is lost thus none occurs? This would certainly explain what I'm seeing. (The PRQ process is a black-box: There's no way to see what happens as it's running.)

If this is true, what other options do I have? Should I allow each PRQ to reboot as necessary, potentially aggravating my customers, or is there another way that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

When the user runs the installer, I check if they are installed in the registry and ask the user if they would like to install them one by one if they are missing anything.  If I decide that one needs a reboot, then I display the prompt to reboot the machine.  It gives me complete control over how I handle the prereqs rather than using the PRQ system.

Comment: interesting idea. I had not thought of that, but it certainly sounds like a workable approach. Have you thought about posting the code that you've written to do this somewhere (e.g., CodeProject, etc?) Seems like that would be a nice resource to have available.